# What is your favorite source formatting tool?

Tags: formatting

We all know that deadlines and/or critical bugfixes and make us forget a bit about source formatting guidelines. Or sometimes you need to work with 3rd party source code which seems to have been coded by someone who doesn't know the meaning of whitespace and readability. What is your favorite tool to tabulate your code (or 3rd party code) to your specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can also use [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) and the [UniversalIndentGUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/), also good for mass tagging.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper's built in tool is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I like Visual Studio's autoformat feature. It's all mass-market and The Man's Tool, but hey, it works & I can read their formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Python itself.... and a vote for Resharper

Answer (score 1):

Emacs:

C-x h (select all)

C-M-\ (indent region)

Answer (score 1):

Heard good things about [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

For Delphi I like [Delforexp](http://www.aew.wur.nl/UK/Delforexp/). Simple and quite fast.

Comment: I absolutely cannot get this to work in Delphi 2007.  I install it and it seems fine until I try to use it.  I then spend about 30 minutes trying to close all the exceptions before it finally causes Delphi to close.  :(

Comment: Hm have not tried it on 2007. But if I magage to get it to work I let you know.

Answer (score 0):

My IDE, IntelliJ, does this while I check in or with a keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

Perl is the language I use most, and [perltidy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Tidy/) does a great job.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [PolyStyle](http://polystyle.com/) as it supports many, many languages, but I'm curious about alternatives, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

[HTMLtidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) is great for HTML formatting.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite tool is [indent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_(Unix)).  It is available off-the shelf in most Unix distributions.  It has tens of options to accommodate most C style conventions.  On Windows it can be easily installed through Cygwin.  Having said that, automated code formatting should be your last resort.  No tool can format code as well as a good programmer.